# How to keep my logitech headset configuration persistent?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, logitech, headset

I have a Logitech H390 usb headset. I plugged it into my laptop with KUbuntu 14.04.
It took some work to have Ubuntu recognize it correctly, but eventually it did.

However every time I logout,hibernate the computer and unplug the headset and then I wake up the computer back and plug in the headset again, the operating system has troubles recognizing the headset.
It sometimes configures the headset as if it were an output-only device (headphones) then I unplug it and plug it in several times and randomly the operating system sees it as if it were an input-only device (mic).
I keep doing so until eventually the operating system recognizes the headset as a duplex (input-output) device.
I wonder if there is a way to make this configuration persistent so that every time I plug my headset in, I don't need to strive to make it work.

Software versions:

Engine: GStreamer
Phonon version 4.13.3
KDE version 4.13.3
Pulseaudio 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1
alsa-base 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4
alsa-utils 1.0.27.2-1ubuntu2
esound-common 0.2.41-11

Comment: If you log in, before you edit your own question, the changes are applied immediately and don't need to go through review.